# MVC Populate input text with ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have another problem wherein I have a method in controller that gets a certain data and place it to the view.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        var data = (from p in db.eTransactions
                    orderby p.id descending
                    select p.id).Take(1);
        ViewBag.id = data;
        return View();
}
```

View

```
<input type="text" value="@(ViewBag.id)"/>
```

instead of the data(which is a certain value) I want to get, the data thrown is like a command in an sql server

```
SELECT TOP (1)     [Extent1].[id] AS [id]    FROM [dbo].[eTransaction] AS [Extent1]    ORDER BY [Extent1].[id] DESC
```

What is needed to do to fix this?

Comment: Try changing `Take(1)` with `Single()` or `First()`. `ViewBag.id` should contain a single scalar value.

Comment: Your query returns a collection (even though it contains only one item). But its terrible practice to use `ViewBag` - pass a model to your view and strongly bind to it using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.yourProperty)`

Comment: can i pass a model to view even if it came from a different class? the value getting taken here is different from the model in the view.

Comment: You can use   ViewBag.id  = db.eTransactions.OrderByDescending(x => x.id).Select(x=>x.id).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Your editing data so ALWAYS use a view model (which will contain all the properties you need in the view - [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: ok the thing that fixed it was adding FirstOrDefault() after the Take(1). see answer below or just use @AsifRaza code. Both of them worked like a charm

Comment: @marvin castro Thank U , Glad i helped u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok the thing that fixed it was adding FirstOrDefault() after the Take(1).

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var data = (from p in db.eTransactions
                orderby p.id descending
                select p.id).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
    ViewBag.id = data;
    return View();
}
```